# I'm trying to perform noise removal operation but its not showing expected satisfying result

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I'm trying to remove noise from an image but I can't do the execution.

Doing this operation to separate the background and the foreground then removing the background and taking the Area of Interest from the foreground to extract features. But the image results are not supporting my idea.

```py
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread(image_path, 1)
img = cv2.resize(img,(512,512))
original_img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
plt.figure(figsize=(15,15))
plt.subplot(3,3,1)
plt.title("original image")
plt.imshow(original_img)

# CLAHE (Contrast Limited Adaptive Histogram Equalization)
clahe = cv2.createCLAHE(clipLimit=2.0, tileGridSize=(8,8))

lab = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)  # convert from BGR to LAB color space
l, a, b = cv2.split(lab)  # split on 3 different channels

l = clahe.apply(l)  # apply CLAHE to the L-channel
#b = clahe.apply(l)+255

lab = cv2.merge((l,a,b))  # merge channels
lab  = cv2.cvtColor(lab, cv2.COLOR_LAB2BGR)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(lab, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)  # convert from LAB to gray
# blur
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (0,0), sigmaX=33, sigmaY=33)
# divide
divide = cv2.divide(gray, blur, scale=255)
# otsu threshold
thresh = cv2.threshold(divide, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
# apply morphology
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (3,3))
morph = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

plt.subplot(3,3,2)
plt.title("gray")
plt.imshow(gray)
plt.subplot(3,3,3)
plt.title("divide")
plt.imshow(divide)
plt.subplot(3,3,4)
plt.title("thresh")
plt.imshow(thresh)
plt.subplot(3,3,5)
plt.title("morph")
plt.imshow(morph)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Output:
[image: Output]

Comment: I don't think this is related to noise removal. You are trying to detect something? What is your "foreground"? All the trees, or only the one on the front? In either case, a simple local threshold like you implemented is not going to get you there. This is a much more complex problem than what a threshold can solve.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Yes, only one tree in the front. Can you suggest me a possible solution?

Comment: What features distinguish the front tree from any of the others. If you do not have any more information and the trees are all the same, then this is a very hard problem. The only feature is that it is the largest!

Comment: Actually, I planned a method to perform disease detection tasks. I was following the plan and the above is the combination of the first 3steps. And my image preprocessing task is to separate the foreground tree that has more focus than other objects in the image.

Comment: so you want to assess focus/blurriness then? that's still a different from "noise removal".